# Trouble while trying to install OpenModelica in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install OpenModelica in Ubuntu 18.04 by following the procedures in the link
https://openmodelica.org/download/download-linux,
but while trying to run the command:

```
wget -q http://build.openmodelica.org/apt/openmodelica.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

I am getting an error as

> "gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found."

I also have tried to install the package using synaptic package manager, but the search did not find any result. But I was able to do the same in Ubuntu 16.04.

Can anyone help me out with this??

Comment: I am able to execute the command fine in Ubuntu 18.04. Try downloading the asc-file manually and check that it is generated by GPG (no proxy or anything changing the file), and then import it using `apt-key add openmodelica.asc`.

Comment: Just tested it on a fresh Xubuntu 18.04 virtual box and it worked as expected.

Comment: I am working under a proxy maybe that is the reason it didn't work. But downloading the asc-file using the bowser and then running the command "sudo apt-key add openmodelica.asc" worked fine.